# Will my timer buffer overflow while waiting for UDP receive?

Tags: c#, wpf, udpclient, system.timers.timer

I am writing a software which will receive data from an UDP packet, and then write it to a file. This is a sample code which I wrote as a console application in order to test the UdpClient class.

```
while(!done)
{
Console.WriteLine("Receiving");
byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
Console.WriteLine("Received");
}
```

I found out that if no UDP packets were received, the while loop will pause at the Receive(ref groupEP) function. Only when a UDP packet is received then will it proceed down to print "Received".

However for the actual program (WPF), in order to save resources, I am using timers instead. Currently it is working fine to update the interface and file, but I have been wondering what will happen if the timer is called every 100ms, while UDP packets are received only every 1 second (assuming I don't know when I will receive the UDPs so I choose 100ms). 
Won't this result in 9 redundant timer calls every 1 second and will this result in overflow? Currently the application is working fine for this scenerio, but I would like to understand why and if there are any possible consequences.

Answer (score 0):

This question is borderline "too broad". You've raised quite a few different issues. That said, trying to keep things short…

How the timer will behave depends on *which* timer you've actually used. If you are using `DispatcherTimer` and are calling `Receive()` from the timer event handler, then you won't get redundant timer events, because you'll be blocking the UI thread instead. Which is actually not good at all, but at least it doesn't result in getting too many timer events.
If you are using some other kind of timer, then yes…issuing a new `Receive()` operation before you have completed the previous one will result in an ever-increasing number of not-yet-completed `Receive()` operations. You could fix this by putting the socket into non-blocking mode, but that would open a whole new can of worms. So…

In fact, you should not be using the blocking `Receive()` method at all, nor a timer for any I/O-related purpose. You should be using an asynchronous version of `ReceiveFrom()`, e.g. `BeginReceiveFrom()`, which you can wrap in a `Task.Factory.FromAsync()` so that you can use `await` instead of dealing with callbacks. (You should use `ReceiveFrom()` so that you can actually obtain the remote endpoint information for the datagram you received).

When using this technique, you will loop with the `await` (if using `FromAsync()`) or you will call `BeginReceiveFrom()` again when processing the completed operation (if you are using the old-style callback mechanisms). With that, you can have just a single receive operation active at a time, but without blocking any thread at all, and thus **no need to use a timer** or other mechanism to poll the socket.

Comment: Won't it be the same if I keep calling ReceiveFrom(), just that I keep generating async threads via my timer call function?

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough. I will edit it to try to improve it. You will only call `BeginReceiveFrom()` once per datagram. After the first call, you do nothing at all until it completes and you've processed the datagram. Then you call it again. You won't use a timer at all in that approach.